# XML deserialization doesn't initialize an array element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the following XML:

```
<ns0:L2CCustomer xmlns:ns0="http://CustomerSyncFromMDM_L2C.L2CCustomer_XML">
  <customerList>
    <customer>
      <DNV_Status>Active</DNV_Status>
      <MDM_ID>1270004</MDM_ID>
      <fullName>JONBER030</fullName>
      <AFFRowID>1-GT6E0X</AFFRowID>
      <addressList>
        <address>
          <addrType>Office</addrType>
          <addrStatus>Active</addrStatus>
          <MDM_ID>2090001</MDM_ID>
          <addrLine1>Tårnveien 14</addrLine1>
          <addrLine2>Buildling 2</addrLine2>
          <city>Ås</city>
          <postalCode>1430</postalCode>
          <country>Norway</country>
          <validCountryISO2>NO</validCountryISO2>
          <AFFRowID>1-GT6E13</AFFRowID>
        </address>
      </addressList>
    </customer>
   </customerList>
</ns0:L2CCustomer>
```

The code that I am using (T is of type AffinitasClientRoot):

```
System.IO.StreamReader r = new System.IO.StreamReader(m.BodyStream);
string cze = r.ReadToEnd();
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
T result;
using (System.IO.TextReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(cze))
{
    result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

The classes:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "L2CCustomer", Namespace = "http://CustomerSyncFromMDM_L2C.L2CCustomer_XML")]
[XmlType("L2CCustomer")]
public class AffinitasClientRoot
{
    [XmlArray("customerList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("customer")]
    public AffinitasClient[] Clients { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "customer")]
[XmlType("customer")]
public class AffinitasClient
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AFFRowID")]
    public string RowId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MDM_ID")]
    public string MdmId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fullName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DNV_Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool Active
    {
        get
        {
            return Status == "Active";
        }
    }
    [XmlArray("addressList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("address")]
    public AffinitasClientAddress[] Addresses { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastUpdatedByTimestamp")]
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    //[XmlElement(ElementName = "Updated")]
    //public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "address")]
[XmlType("address")]
public class AffinitasClientAddress
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AFFRowID")]
    public string RowId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MDM_ID")]
    public string MdmId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "addrType")]
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "addrStatus")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool Active
    {
        get
        {
            return Status == "Active";
        }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "addrLine1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "addrLine2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "postalCode")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "validCountryISO2")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastUpdatedByTimestamp")]
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialization does not throw any exception, but the Clients array is null. Any ideas how I can solve it? I've been trying to do it for a few hours now and I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AffinitasClientRoot` class should look like that:

```
public class AffinitasClientRoot
{
    [XmlArray("customerList", Namespace="")] // here!!!!
    [XmlArrayItem("customer")]
    public AffinitasClient[] Clients { get; set; }
}
```

I.e. insert the `Namespace=""` declaration to 'switch back' from 'named namespace' to 'nameless namespace'.